# merging 2 dynamic arrays 1 element at a time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 dynamic arrays of HTML elements

let's say that there is array **A = [1, 2 , 3]**, and array B = *[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]* (they have different lengths that can change in time)

I need a way to merge them both to create array C, so that array C will be a mixture of 1 element from A, then 1 element from B, then one from A .. and so on till they're both done.

Ex: I need array C = [**1**, *4*, **2**, *5* , **3** , *6* , *7* , *8*]

Is there a way for me to do that using javascript or jquery?

Comment: use loops and `c.push()`

Comment: I know i'll need to use loops, but I was hoping for an answer a little more detailed than that :)

Comment: I was hoping for some code showing searches and tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the classic `for` loop. Use `Math.max` to get the higher length.

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3];
let B = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let C = [];

for (i = 0; i < Math.max(A.length, B.length); i++) {
  if (A[i]) C.push(A[i]);  //Push if A[i] exist
  if (B[i]) C.push(B[i]);  //Push if B[i] exist
}

console.log(C);
```

Will also work if `A` has more array elements than `B`

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let B = [8, 9, 10];
let C = [];

for (i = 0; i < Math.max(A.length, B.length); i++) {
  if (A[i]) C.push(A[i]);
  if (B[i]) C.push(B[i]);
}

console.log(C);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the larger array and push the elements to results from both the arrays in the iteration. Here is a way:

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3];
var B = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var result = B.reduce((a, item, i) => {
  if (A[i]) {
    a.push(A[i]);
  }
  
  a.push(item);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if A has more elements than B?

Comment: @31piy what does "reduce" do exactly? i checked the documentation on MDN but i didn't quite understand it "The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value."

Comment: @Cid -- I've clearly mentioned in the answer to loop on the larger array.

Comment: @miimeg -- Basically, `reduce` here is looping over an array, and in each iteration, it pushes the elements from both the original arrays to an accumulator, `a`. Finally, when loop ends, it returns the accumulator.